# Show back button instead of drawer button - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Flutter project which uses material design, that as I go through routes the appbar will show the backbutton. Recently, I just implemented a drawer in my project, and the drawer icon overrides the back icon. I essentially want to undo this, showing the back button, for certain screens, and show the menu button for other screens, almost like when I define the drawer having a `showIcon: false` property? I understand this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926597/flutter-drawer-button-shown-instead-of-back-button) is a similar question, but no code is shown for the question or the solution... My drawer looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  //appbar is here
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Title"),
  ),
  drawer: drawer,
  body: _buildBody(),
);
```

And I define drawer here:

```
var drawer = Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      //My listTiles and UserAccountsDrawerHeader are removed for simplicity
    ],
  ),
);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please edit your question showing how you navigate through different screens in your app? You can pass different `AppBar` objects for different `Scaffold`s within different widgets, but it seems like you only operate with a single `Scaffold` object.

Comment: Jack do let me know if that didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```dart
AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
    onPressed: () {}, // Handle your on tap here.
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
  ),
)
```

---

#### Screenshot:

[image]

#### Full code:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyPage()));

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page1())),
              child: Text("Go to Drawer Page"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2())),
              child: Text("Go to Back button Page"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// This has drawer
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}


// This has back button and drawer
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I still want the drawer to be available on Page 2, just with a swipe from the right edge left.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I have updated the code, now it will have back icon for page 2 but also a drawer which is available by swiping from right to left.

Answer (score 2):

```
AppBar(
leading: Builder(
builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },

  );
},
),
)
```

Comment: Combining this solution with using endDrawer instead of drawer, you can have back button and drawer facility together.